# Nested Header Panels

Tags: gwt

I am trying to nest HeaderPanels taking advantage of the header and footer capabilities in my webpage.

The top level HeaderPanel works fine, but the second HeaderPanel in the center of the top panel does not appear. Here is sample code:

```java
import com.google.gwt.core.client.EntryPoint;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.HTML;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.HeaderPanel;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.RootLayoutPanel;

public class Admin implements EntryPoint {

private final HeaderPanel topPanel = new HeaderPanel();
private final HeaderPanel centerPanel = new HeaderPanel();

@Override
public void onModuleLoad() {

    topPanel.setHeaderWidget(new HTML("top header"));

    topPanel.setFooterWidget(new HTML("top footer"));

    centerPanel.setHeaderWidget(new HTML("center header"));
    centerPanel.setFooterWidget(new HTML("center footer"));
    centerPanel.add(new HTML("center center"));

    topPanel.setContentWidget(centerPanel);
    RootLayoutPanel.get().add(topPanel);
}
}
```

The 'center header', 'center footer' and 'center center' never appear on the webpage.

I also tried using a DocLayoutPanel in the center and it didn't work either.

I suspect that these only work when attached to the RootLayoutPanel.

Is nested Header or Doc layout panels possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you try the Chrome inspect, there's something similar in IE9 too, you'll see that that the center widget has 0 height. If you set the size it will work. I would use a DockLayoutPanel. You can nest DockLayoutPanels.

Comment: Thanks. Just what the doctor ordered. Your comment pushed me to try Firebug, which was a good learning experience.